Copying File to Redshift from S3 Bucket
I am trying to move some data from a CSV in S3 to a Redshift table. The date column is giving me a hard time however.
When opened in a text editor, the date is formatted like this: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS",
however when I open the file in excel, the formula bar lists the date as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM/PM, and the actual table doesn't even include the seconds, or the AM/PM.
When I run the query in the image, I get this error: Date value did not match format specified [yyyy-MM-dd]
And when I remove the DATEFORMAT line entirely, I get: Invalid Date Format - length must be 10 or more.
What am I doing wrong? The column in the table is expecting a date in the format of yyyy-MM-dd, but my boss assured me that the time shouldn't affect that
enter image description here

Did you try dateformat ‘auto’? Copy it in as a varchar, what exactly does it display?  Never open csv in excel, it always mangles it

Can you provide table DDL and the line form stl_load_errors?  It could be many things.  Is the column a date or a timestamp?  Is it quoted?  Is it failing on the first line?  Is there a header row? etc.

Got it, thanks guys. The problem was the header line, once I added IGNOREHEADER 1, I was fine

I got the answer. My problem was that it was reading the header line as data. Once I added the line IGNOREHEADER 1, it worked. Somewhat misleading error.
